# Can you pause all apps making an audio output in Android Studio?

Tags: android, youtube

I was wandering if it would be possible to pause all audio outputs in Android Studio.
As an example, let's say you were listening to Youtube Music or Spotify, what code wouldbe able to pause them. Not mute them. Pause them. Additionally, if it's possible could you make it that it goes back a few seconds (etc. 5s or 2s). Also, I would like it not to require to use any API's as I'd like it to be universal but if that's not possible, I would like it to be able to pause and revert a few seconds in Youtube Music (Premium) and the default Android Music Player.

Thank you.

Comment: Using earphones most of time there is a button to pause an audio being played, it works for YouTube videos at least. So I guess Android Studio should propose such a feature.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison there's nothing to propose. If OP wants to control media sessions from other apps he needs to implement a [`MediaController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController). Sadly it's rather invasive because you need to obtain notification listener permission in order to use it.